# Classification using a regex tokenizer

Tags: python, datetime, regex

This is an updated version of my previous post [found here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/170905/classification-of-date-time-datetime). Mainly as a courtesy for anyone interested. I have Taken most of the advise. Apart from a couple of things.

1. I can't figure out how to use readline()
2. Input normalization is now done by an optional function passed
3. Not a pure regex solution

The terminology has also changed quite a bit since the previous version.

I'm interested in all feedback. In particular, how I can format the regular expressions in the list labeled `time_features`, to look 'right'.

Any better way to implement an idea or simplify it.

What I don't like about it. Is that just creating the classifier object has as a side effect of creating files. Which I want, as it lets me populate the files with the `tokenized` output printed from the error msg. There's more than likely a better way.

Files associated with this example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3HIB_5rVAxmbUJ4SjRMT3lBNlU

Here are some input/output pairs:

---

```
Enter time to classify as Date/Time/DateTime:
>?July 3 2017 8am
DateTime
Enter time to classify as Date/Time/DateTime:
>?2:00
Time
Enter time to classify as Date/Time/DateTime:
>?1.2.2017
Date
Enter time to classify as Date/Time/DateTime:
>?15 september 2017 19:00
DateTime
Enter time to classify as Date/Time/DateTime:
>?August 3 12:00

CLASSIFIER: Time FAILED TO CLASSIFY:

Raw string:                   August 3 12:00
Formatted string:             August 3 12:00
key:                          [4, 0, 0, 2, 0]
----------------------------------------------
Enter time to classify as Date/Time/DateTime:
>?
```

---

```
import re
import itertools
import operator


class ClassificationException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, output):
        pass

class Classifier(object):
    def __init__(self,  classifier_name, classifications, features, file_extension='.txt', normalize_input=None, re_flags=''):
        '''
        Create a classifier object that classifies string input based upon features extracted by regular expressions

        :param classifier_name: The prefix for files associated with this classifier
        :param classifications: The potential classifications of the data
        :param features: A list of regular expressions, each expression is a feature. Features should be ordered from
        highest to lowest importance
        :param file_extension: The file extension of files associated to this classifier defaults to .txt
        :param normalize_input: Designed to take a function to normalize the string input. Defaults to identity
        :param re_flags: Flags passed to the regular expression engine, defaults to none. It should be a string, similar to
        the inline syntax. eg. 'ismx' => IGNORECASE|DOTALL|MULTILINE|VERBOSE
        '''

        #This is used to identify files that belong to this classifier
        self.name = classifier_name
        #The potential classifications
        self.classifications = classifications
        #Create a function that extracts the given features
        self.create_extractor_from_table(features, re_flags)
        self.file_extension = file_extension
        #Create files to contain the match_codes. Useful when the user wants to populate the response table
        self.create_files(self.name, self.file_extension, *self.classifications)
        #Read response matches and construct the lookup table
        self.create_response_table()
        #Input normalisation defaults to an identity function
        self.normalize_function(normalize_input)

    def create_extractor_from_table(self, features, re_flags):
        flag_lookup = {'i': re.IGNORECASE, 'm': re.MULTILINE, 's': re.DOTALL, 'x': re.VERBOSE}
        if 2 <= len(re_flags) <= 4:
            flags = [flag_lookup[i] for i in re_flags]
            flags = list(itertools.accumulate(flags, func=operator.or_))[-1]
        elif len(re_flags) == 1:
            flags = flag_lookup[re_flags]
        else:
            flags = 0
        def feature_extractor(string):
            #Create a list of re.finditer generators
            feature_table = [re.finditer(feature, string, flags) for feature in features]
            #Unpack the above generators
            match_code = [(index, ii.start()) for index, i in enumerate(feature_table) for ii in i]
            #Sort the features based upon their start position
            match_code = sorted(match_code, key=lambda x: x[1])
            #Remove duplicate matches, the first match gets priority over the rest
            match_code = [next(group) for i, group in itertools.groupby(match_code, key=lambda x: x[1])]
            match_code = [i[0] for i in match_code]
            return match_code
        self.feature_extractor = feature_extractor

    @staticmethod
    def create_files(prefix, extension, *file_names):
        for file in file_names:
            with open('{}_{}{}'.format(prefix, file, extension), 'a') as f:
                pass

    @staticmethod
    def read_file(file_prefix, file_name, file_extension):
        with open('{}_{}{}'.format(file_prefix, file_name, file_extension), 'r') as f:
            lines = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != '', f)
            contents = [[int(ii.group()) for ii in re.finditer(r'\d+', i)] for i in lines]
            return contents

    @staticmethod
    def append_file(file_prefix, file_name, file_extension, data):
        with open('{}{}{}'.format(file_prefix, file_name, file_extension), 'a') as f:
            for i in data:
                f.write('{}{}'.format(str(i), '\n'))

    def create_response_table(self):
        self.response_table = {classification: self.read_file(self.name, classification, self.file_extension)
                          for classification in self.classifications}

    def normalize_function(self, func):
        def identity_function(arg):
            return arg
        if not func:
            self.normalize_function = identity_function
        else:
            self.normalize_function = func

    def failed_to_classify_output(self, raw_string, formatted_string, match_code):
        '''
        Print the failed classification for review
        '''
        def align(text):  # Column width
            return ' ' * (30 - len(text))

        row = [[]] * 4 # I know this not pythonic but it allows me to lay out my code nicely
        # Column 1
        row[0] = '\nCLASSIFIER: {} FAILED TO CLASSIFY:\n\n'.format(self.name)
        row[1] = 'Raw string:'
        row[2] = 'Formatted string:'
        row[3] = 'key:'
        # Add column 2 to column 1
        row[1] = '{}{}{}\n'.format(row[1], align(row[1]), raw_string)
        row[2] = '{}{}{}\n'.format(row[2], align(row[2]), formatted_string)
        row[3] = '{}{}{}\n'.format(row[3], align(row[3]), match_code)

        output = ''.join((i for ii in row for i in ii))
        return (output + '{}'.format('-' * len(max(row, key=lambda x: len(x)))))

    def __call__(self, string):

        #Normalize string
        normalized_string = self.normalize_function(string)
        #Extract features
        match_code = self.feature_extractor(normalized_string)
        #Check for membership of the match_code in the response table
        members = [(key, len(value)) for key, value in self.response_table.items()
                   for i in value if str(i) in str(match_code)]
        #Sort by match length
        result = sorted(members, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)


        # The classification will be first value if it exists
        classification = None
        try:
            classification = next(iter(result))[0]
        except StopIteration:
            pass

        if classification:
            return classification
        else:
            #If it failed to classify print out an error msg and raise a ClassificationException
            error_msg = self.failed_to_classify_output(string, normalized_string, match_code)
            raise ClassificationException(error_msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':

        def normalization(string):
            _string = re.sub(r'\s', ' ', str(string)).strip()
            return _string


        time_features = ['\d+',
                         '[/\-.|]',
                         ':',
                         'am|pm|AM|PM',
                         'jan(?:uary)?|feb(ruary)?|mar(ch)?|apr(il)?|may|jun(e)?|jul(y)?\
                         |aug(ust)?|sep(tember)?|oct(ober)?|nov(ember)?|dec(ember)?',
                         'mon(day)?|tue(sday)?|wed(nesday)?|thu(rsday)?|fri(day)?|sat(urday)?|sun(day)?',
                         ',',
                         'today|tomorrow|yesterday',
                         'aest',
                         '\w+']

        time_classifications = ['Date', 'Time', 'DateTime']

        time_classifier = Classifier('Time', time_classifications, time_features,
                                     normalize_input=normalization, re_flags='i')

        while True:
            text = input('Enter time to classify as Date/Time/DateTime:\n>?')
            try:
                result = time_classifier(text)
            except ClassificationException as e:
                print(e)
            else:
                print(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a great idea for you to be documenting your functions. Keep that up.

Running a PEP8 linter will tell you, among other things, that your comments should have a space between the # and the first word.

I think you've already smelled the issue where you start to write 'I know this not pythonic'. I'll still recommend that it be changed. At the least, perform a literal initializer:

```
row = [
   '\nCLASSIFIER: {} FAILED TO CLASSIFY:\n\n'.format(self.name),
   'Raw string:',
   'Formatted string:',
   'key:'
]
```

Finally, it looks like you have no facility to exit the program. That feature seems useful (rather than being forced to Ctrl^C).

Comment: Well, I didn't know that, must admit I've been putting off reading PEP 8... Actually. Your solution is nicer, I liked reading `row[1]` as the index was almost like a comment. Hadn't thought of the above layout.